# How to Return an Array of Strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

For example, I have in the main file

```
1) char ** array[NUMBER];
2) array = build_array();
```

and in an imported file

```
char ** build_array()
{
  char ** array[NUMBER];
  strings[0] = "A";
  strings[1] = "B";
  return (char *) strings;
}
```

However, at line 2 in the main file, I get the error: `"incompatible types when assigning to type 'char **[(unsighed int)NUMBER]' from type 'char **'`

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the actual code? Where is `strings` defined? Why do you take a pointer to a literal string? Etc...

Comment: Is `array` supposed to be `strings`? Are you trying to return a pointer to a stack allocated object?

Comment: I just want to call the build_array() function and return the array of strings (pointers to char arrays) to use in main.

Comment: strings aren't pointers to char arrays, they are just pointer to chars.

Comment: Right, my mistake. How would I do this?

Comment: Would I return a pointer to an array of pointers? How would I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There seem to be some confusion about what a string is in C. In C, a null terminated sequence of `char`s is considered a string. It is usually represented by `char*`.

> I just want to call the `build_array()` function and return the array of strings

You pretty much can't return an array, neither a pointer to a local array. You could however pass the array to `build_array` as an argument, as well as its `size`, and fill that instead.

```
void build_array( char* strings[], size_t size )
{
  // make sure size >= 2 here, based on your actual logic
  strings[0] = "A";
  strings[1] = "B";
}
...later called as:...
char *array[NUMBER];
build_array(array, NUMBER);
```

The alternatives are to return a pointer to a global or static allocated array, which would make your function non-reentrant. You probably don't care about this now, but is bad practice so I would recommend you avoid going that route.

Comment: Thank you so much. It now compiles, however, when I try to print the contents, nothing prints or gibberish prints. Is there an issue with assigning values to the array?

Comment: @LearningPython: We have seen so little of your code, that I wouldn't know. How is `NUMBER` defined? How do you attempt to print the contents?

Comment: @LearningPython: Well I'm intrigued... what was it?

Comment: Using `int` for an array size? Really? ;)

Comment: @Chris Lutz: If in C++ I would have gone with `std::size_t` which is unsigned, is that your point?

Comment: @K-ballo - `size_t` is a type in C as well, it's the type of the value returned by `sizeof`. (`size_t` is declared in `stddef.h` and `stdlib.h`)

Answer (score 9):

As littleadv pointed out, there are several problems with your code:

- Mismatch between `char **` and `char **[ ]`
- Returning a pointer to a local variable
- Etc.

This example might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define NUMBER 2
#define MAX_STRING 80

char **
build_array ()
{
  int i = 0;
  char **array = malloc (sizeof (char *) * NUMBER);
  if (!array)
    return NULL;
  for (i = 0; i < NUMBER; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc (MAX_STRING + 1);
    if (!array[i]) {
      free (array);
      return NULL;
    }
  }
  strncpy (array[0], "ABC", MAX_STRING);
  strncpy (array[1], "123", MAX_STRING);
  return array;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char **my_array = build_array ();
  if (!my_array) {
    printf ("ERROR: Unable to allocate my_array!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    printf ("my_array[0]=%s, my_array[1]=%s.\n",
      my_array[0], my_array[1]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this great example `NUMBER` is known in advance. Could we get the length of the returned array from the caller function if that number is decided inside `build_array()` ?

Comment: Sure.  One way is to pass #/elements back to the caller as an "out" parameter.  EXAMPLE: `char ** build_array(int * nelms)`, then inside build_array(): `*nelms = number;`

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is `char**`, while you're assigning it to `char**[]`, that's incompatible.

Other than that you should post the actual code that you have problem with, the code you posted doesn't compile and doesn't make much sense.

In order to fix your code, the function should be returning `char **[NUMBER]`. Note also, that you're casting the return value to `char*` instead of `char**` that you declared (or `char **[NUMBER]` that it should be, and in fact - is).

Oh, and returning a pointer to a local variable, as you do in your case, is a perfect recipe for crashes and undefined behavior.

What you probably meant was:

```
char *array[NUMBER];
int ret = build_array(array, NUMBER);
// do something with return value or ignore it
```

and in an imported file

```
int build_array(char **arr, int size)
{
  // check that the size is large enough, and that the
  // arr pointer is not null, use the return value to
  // signal errors
  arr[0] = "A";
  arr[1] = "B";
  return 0; // asume 0 is OK, use enums or defines for that
}
```

Comment: What should the return type be to return an array of strings?